# Hadoop 2.2.0 jar files missing

Tags: hadoop

I have hadoop-2.2.0 installed and was trying to run the mapreduce examples code that comes bundled with it. But, it fails every time with the `ClassNotFoundException` and the reason I found out is because of what is set up in the `hadoop.sh` file. The below is what is present in the sh file and none of the class files are bundled in the installation. I do see that they are present in the source.

```
if [ "$COMMAND" = "fs" ] ; then
  CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell
elif [ "$COMMAND" = "version" ] ; then
  CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo
elif [ "$COMMAND" = "jar" ] ; then
  CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
elif [ "$COMMAND" = "checknative" ] ; then
  CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeLibraryChecker
elif [ "$COMMAND" = "distcp" ] ; then
  CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp
  CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${TOOL_PATH}
elif [ "$COMMAND" = "daemonlog" ] ; then
  CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.log.LogLevel
elif [ "$COMMAND" = "archive" ] ; then
  CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.tools.HadoopArchives
  CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${TOOL_PATH}
elif [[ "$COMMAND" = -*  ]] ; then
    # class and package names cannot begin with a -
    echo "Error: No command named \`$COMMAND' was found. Perhaps you meant \`hadoop ${COMMAND#-}'"
    exit 1
else
  CLASS=$COMMAND
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop/,file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.13)
```

Comment: can you list the full command you ran and the error message you got?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the issue. The YARN (for mapreduce) and DFS processes needs to be running in the background to run any hadoop job. I missed those being a n00b to Hadoop. To launch those 2 processes, type `start-yarn` and `start-dfs` from a command window. They both launch 2 console windows each and spit out a lot of diagnostic info.